# Laptop requirements for Blender

Tags: performance

I have recently downloaded Blender. But because my laptop is old i'm thinking of buying this HP Laptop (Pavilion 17-e100sv) with these characteristics:

Intel Core i3-3110M Processor-2.40 GHz
RAM: 4 GB - DDR3 SDRAM
500 GB - Serial ATA - 5400 rpm
2GB AMD Radeon HD 8670M graphics card.

Can you please tell me if these technical characteristics are enough for Blender?
If not, what do you recommend in terms of RAM, etc?

Please help out, since I will only buy a new laptop for Blender and I don't want to pay for something and then realize that it will not perform when i render an animation.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Blender should run okay on old hardware for some tinkering. I would only worry about buying a new computer if you experience performance issues with more complex models and rendering (especially Cycles). If you really need a lot of horse power, go for a desktop machine, laptop performance isn't ever great.

See the general specifications:
http://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Dedicated Nvidia cards are recommended (CUDA support!), you should avoid ATI/AMD from what I've read (buggy OpenCL support etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, and the recommendation regarding the graphics card. Perhaps i should go for a desktop machine...I am new at this and this site, that's why i didn't find the information and asked the same question. Thanks again for all.

Comment: No problem and you're welcome :) Just get a copy of Blender and see how it works and if you wanna continue with 3D stuff. If you can use a portable computer more than a desktop machine, then a notebook is also ok. It's just not as powerful as a desktop computer.